# Problem to cite several author with beamer

Tags: beamer, bibtex

I am making a presentation with beamer. If I include only citations with one or two authors there isn't problem but compilation (pdflatex and bibtex) fails when I include citations with more than two authors:

> [19] (./presentacion.bbl
>   ! Undefined control sequence.
>   \beamer@sort #1#2->\long \def \beamer@todo 
>                                              {#1}\def \beamer@ospec {}\beamer@...
>   l.4 ...1990)Willson, Rice y Westoby}]{Willson1990}
>
> ?

Same bibliography doesn't produce problems if I use document class{article} instead of beamer.

My code is this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{estilo}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\citep{willson1990}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Referencias}
            \bibliographystyle{estilo}
    \begin{footnotesize}
\bibliography{biblio2.bib} 
\end{footnotesize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Someone knows what is the problem?

Thanks in advanced

Diego Salazar

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and make your code theoretically compilable. At [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) you can find how to include a bibliography in your example.

Comment: Maybe it's a little bit late, but for someone else that gets here with the same problem: you could try with `\bibliography{biblio2}` (without the `.bib`). Also, you could try setting `natbib` package with [numbers], [sort&compress] or others i.e `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`. The other thing that I can notice is that you are using a customized bibliographystyle (`estilo`). I also tried with my own style modifying apalike2, and I did, indeed, have the same problem you did. I don't know why is this, but well.. If you could upload your `.bst` file, perhaps someone could help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because without having the custom bibliography style "estilo" this question can only be answered with a very good crystal ball.